# $x\wedge a \wedge b=x \Rightarrow x\wedge b=x$ in a lattice viewed as an algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lattice-orders

A lattice is an algebraic structure $(L,\wedge,\vee)$ such that, $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are commutative, associative and abosrbing binary operations, i.e.

$$a \wedge (b\vee a)=a,\quad a\vee(a\wedge b)=a.$$

I want to show
$$x\wedge a \wedge b=x \Rightarrow x\wedge b=x.$$

Working from a lattice as a poset, and defining $a\wedge b$ as the essential source of $\{a,b\}$, i.e
$$x=a\wedge b \iff (x\leq a) \quad (x\leq b) \quad \forall y\in L (y\leq a \text{ and } y\leq b)\Rightarrow y\leq x.$$
Then the result follows. But how do I show this without a relation

Comment: Note: “algebraic lattice” has a different meaning: it is a complete lattice in which every element is a (possibly infinite) join of compact elements. It does not mean “lattice viewed as an algebra”.

Comment: P.S. You forgot that $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are also idempotent.

Comment: Doesn't idempotency follow from the other axioms? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: They can be derived using the absorption laws, but one usually includes them so that you can define upper subsemilattice and lower subsemilattices by taking a subset of axioms.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x\wedge a \wedge b = x$, then
$$\begin{align*}
x\wedge b &= (x\wedge a\wedge b) \wedge b &\text{(substitution)}\\
&= (x\wedge a)\wedge (b\wedge b)&\text{(associativity)}\\
&= (x\wedge a) \wedge b&\text{(idempotency)}\\
&= x\wedge a \wedge b & \text{(associativity)}\\
&= x. &\text{(substitution)}
\end{align*}
$$